# How to prevent apikey, domain and url to show to app user in firebase angularjs

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

To use firebase - in web project firebase doc says we need to add config in java script file. Like this:

```
<script>
        // Initialize Firebase
        var config = {
            apiKey: <your key value>,
            authDomain: <your domain value>,
            databaseURL: <url value>,
            storageBucket: <bucket value>,
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(config);
    </script>
```

My question: is this not an security hole? Any one can right click on page, and click on "view source code" in browser and can see all these values?

Please correct me, if i am wrong or misunderstood Usage/any thing?

Comment: You can just restrict your api key and that's it [https://medium.com/@impaachu/how-to-secure-your-firebase-project-even-when-your-api-key-is-publicly-available-a462a2a58843](https://medium.com/@impaachu/how-to-secure-your-firebase-project-even-when-your-api-key-is-publicly-available-a462a2a58843)

Answer (score 1):

Alfonso from the Firebase Auth team.

You don't need to worry, all of these values are meant to be public. Our anti abuse checks are performed in the server side, and there is no security hole if someone reads your config values from viewing your site's source.